# Bone weights to GPU in vectors

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, vector, gpu

I've been working on skeletal animation using OPenGL and sending bone weight influences to the GPU in a struct containing a pair of arrays, however changing these arrays to vectors doesn't seem to work (as in the model ceases to render, as if the bone information was missing or wrong in some manner).

Asides from the declaration of the vectors within the struct, the code path is identical. I've debugged through and ensured the size/values of the elements are okay. The only thing I can think of is that C++ is freeing the contents of the vectors before it can be uploaded to the GPU, but I've seen no evidence to support that claim.

It's worth noting that the resizes used are to make the structure compatible with the existing array functionality and will be removed to allow for dynamic scaling after this issue is resolved.

Here's the structure as it stands, using vectors:

```
struct VertexBoneData
{
    std::vector<glm::uint> IDs;
    std::vector<float> weights;
    VertexBoneData()
    {
        Reset();
        IDs.resize(NUM_BONES_PER_VEREX);
        weights.resize(NUM_BONES_PER_VEREX);
    };

    void Reset()
    {
        IDs.clear();
        weights.clear();
    }

    void AddBoneData(glm::uint p_boneID, float p_weight);
};
```

Edit: Additional information.

Here's the loop to get the bone information in to the struct:

```
void Skeleton::LoadBones(glm::uint baseVertex, const aiMesh* mesh, std::vector<VertexBoneData>& bones)
{
    for (glm::uint i = 0; i < p_mesh->mNumBones; i++) {
        glm::uint boneIndex = 0;
        std::string boneName(mesh->mBones[i]->mName.data);

        if (_boneMap.find(boneName) == _boneMap.end()) {
            //Allocate an index for a new bone
            boneIndex = _numBones;
            _numBones++;
            BoneInfo bi;
            _boneInfo.push_back(bi);
            SetMat4x4(_boneInfo[boneIndex].boneOffset, mesh->mBones[i]->mOffsetMatrix);
            _boneMap[boneName] = boneIndex;
        }
        else {
            boneIndex = _boneMap[boneName];
        }

        for (glm::uint j = 0; j < mesh->mBones[i]->mNumWeights; j++) {
            glm::uint vertId = baseVertex + mesh->mBones[i]->mWeights[j].mVertexId;
            float weight = mesh->mBones[i]->mWeights[j].mWeight;
            bones[vertId].AddBoneData(boneIndex, weight);
        }
    }
}
```

The code to add the ID/weights to the vertex:

```
void VertexBoneData::AddBoneData(glm::uint p_boneID, float p_weight)
{
    for (glm::uint i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(IDs); i++) {
        if (weights[i] == 0.0) {
            IDs[i] = p_boneID;
            weights[i] = p_weight;
            return;
        }
    }
    assert(0);  //Should never get here - more bones than we have space for
}
```

Loop to load the Skeleton and insert to the VBO object from the Mesh class:

```
if (_animator.HasAnimations())
{
    bones.resize(totalIndices);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _scene->mNumMeshes; ++i){
    _animator.LoadSkeleton(_subMeshes[i].baseVertex, _scene->mMeshes[i], bones);
    }
    _vertexBuffer[2].AddData(&bones);
}
```

Insert to the VBO object:

```
void VertexBufferObject::AddData(void* ptr_data)
{
    data = *static_cast<std::vector<BYTE>*>(ptr_data);
}
```

Finally the code to add the information to the GPU from the Mesh class:

```
_vertexBuffer[2].BindVBO();
_vertexBuffer[2].UploadDataToGPU(GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(BONE_ID_LOCATION);
glVertexAttribIPointer(BONE_ID_LOCATION, 4, GL_INT, sizeof(VertexBoneData), (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(BONE_WEIGHT_LOCATION);
glVertexAttribPointer(BONE_WEIGHT_LOCATION, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexBoneData), (const GLvoid*)(sizeof(VertexBoneData) / 2));
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually contain anything useful to helping you with your problem. It's fine aside from the constructor being silly. I don't know why you thought the problem would be there, it's likely on the c++/gpu barrier (you didn't even bother to tell us if you're using d3d or OpenGL)

Comment: Fair points, I was trying to reduce the amount of code I posted. I've just added a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't possibly work. A `std::vector` instance is an object that internally contains a pointer to dynamically allocated data.

So with this definition:

```
struct VertexBoneData
{
    std::vector<glm::uint> IDs;
    std::vector<float> weights;
```

The values for the `IDs` and `weights` aren't stored directly in the structure. The are in dynamically allocated heap memory. The structure only contains the `vector` objects, which contain pointers and some bookkeeping attributes.

You can't store these structs directly in an OpenGL buffer, and have the GPU access the data. OpenGL won't know what do with `vector` objects.

Comment: Aha, yes. That would fit with the behaviour I'm seeing. That being said, I still need to resize the structure dynamically AND have it available to the GPU. I can't think of an elegant way to solve this off the top of my head, but thanks for solving my initial quandary!

Comment: @Mark Add a method to your struct that dumps its content into a buffer instead of using the bone array/vector as a buffer, and then pass that buffer to your shader.

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution, the problem I see though is that the weights aren't added sequentially; i.e. a weight and ID for bone i will be added, next will be a weight and ID for bone j, then bone q maybe then bone i again.